# Datediff on 2 rows of a table with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data looks like the following

```
TicketID      OwnedbyTeamT       Createddate         ClosedDate
1234          A          
1234          A         01/01/2019            01/05/2019 
1234          A         10/05/2018            10/07/2018
1234          B         10/04/2019            10/08/2018
1234          finance   11/01/2018            11/11/2018
1234          B         12/02/2018
```

Now, I want to calculate the datediff between the closeddates for teams A, and B, if the max closeddate for team A is greater than max closeddate team B. If it is smaller or null I don't want to see them. So, for example,I want to see only one record like this :

```
TicketID      (Datediff)result-days
 1234            86
```

and for another tickets, display the info. For example, if the conditions aren't met then:

```
TicketID      (Datediff)result-days
   2456            -1111111
```

Data sample for 2456:

```
TicketID      OwnedbyTeamT       Createddate         ClosedDate
2456          A          
2456          A         10/01/2019            10/05/2019 
2456          B         08/05/2018            08/07/2018
2456          B         06/04/2019            06/08/2018
2456         finance    11/01/2018            11/11/2018
2456          B         12/02/2018
```

I want to see the difference in days between  01/05/2019 for team A, and

10/08/2018 for team B.

Here is the query that I wrote, however, all I see is -1111111, any help please?:

```
SELECT A.incidentid, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN Max(B.[build validation]) <> 'No data' 
                AND Max(A.crfs) <> 'No data' 
                AND Max(B.[build validation]) < Max(A.crfs) THEN 
           Datediff(day, Max(B.[build validation]), Max(A.crfs)) 
           ELSE -1111111 
         END ) AS 'Days-CRF-diff' 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT incidentid, 
                        Iif(( ownedbyteam = 'B' 
                              AND titlet LIKE '%Build validation%' ), Cast( 
                        closeddatetimet AS NVARCHAR(255)), 'No data') AS 
                               'Build Validation' 
        FROM   incidentticketspecifics) B
       INNER JOIN (SELECT incidentid, 
                          Iif(( ownedbyteamt = 'B' 
                                 OR ownedbyteamt = 
                                    'Finance' ), 
                          Cast( 
                          closeddatetimet AS NVARCHAR(255)), 'No data') AS 
                          'CRFS' 
                   FROM   incidentticketspecifics 
                   GROUP  BY incidentid, 
                             ownedbyteamt, 
                             closeddatetimet) CRF 
               ON A.incidentid = B.incidentid 
GROUP  BY A.incidentid
```

Comment: please also include sample data for `2456`

Comment: @Squirrel, exactly like 1234, just different dates!

Comment: then please show how does that looks like. We can't imagine

Comment: @Squirrel, posted!

Comment: is the query that you posted complete ? I see you have alias `A.incidentid` but I don't a table with alias `A` see it anywhere in the query

Comment: please verify your sample data and the expected result and also the query that you posted. For `2456`, `MAX for A` is `10/05/2019` and `MAX for B` is `08/07/2018` why the expected result is `-1111111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample query is quite complicated and has conditions not mentioned in the text.  It doesn't really help.

> I want to calculate the datediff between the closeddates for teams A, and B, if the max closeddate for team A is greater than max closeddate team B. If it is smaller or null I don't want to see them.

I think you want this per `TicketId`.  You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TicketId,
       DATEDIFF(day,
                MAX(CASE WHEN OwnedbyTeamT = 'B' THEN ClosedDate END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN OwnedbyTeamT = 'A' THEN ClosedDate END) as diff
               )
FROM incidentticketspecifics its
GROUP BY TicketId
HAVING  MAX(CASE WHEN OwnedbyTeamT = 'A' THEN ClosedDate END) >
       MAX(CASE WHEN OwnedbyTeamT = 'B' THEN ClosedDate END)
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following answer will be of help.

With two subqueries for the two teams (A and B), the max date for every Ticket is brought. A left join between these two tables is performed to have these information in the same row in order to perform `DATEDIFF`. The last `WHERE` clause keeps the row with the dates greater for A team than team B.

Please change `[YourDB]` and `[MytableName]` in the following code with your names.

```
--Select the items to be viewed in the final view along with the difference in days
SELECT A.[TicketID],A.[OwnedbyTeamT], A.[Max_DateA],B.[OwnedbyTeamT], B.[Max_DateB], DATEDIFF(dd,B.[Max_DateB],A.[Max_DateA]) AS My_Diff
FROM 
(
--The following subquery creates a table A with the max date for every project for team A
  SELECT [TicketID]
      ,[OwnedbyTeamT]
      ,MAX([ClosedDate]) AS Max_DateA
  FROM [YourDB].[dbo].[MytableName]
  GROUP BY [TicketID],[OwnedbyTeamT]
  HAVING [OwnedbyTeamT]='A')A
--A join between view A and B to bring the max dates for every project
  LEFT JOIN (
--The max date for every project for team B
  SELECT [TicketID]
      ,[OwnedbyTeamT]
      ,MAX([ClosedDate]) AS Max_DateB
  FROM [YourDB].[dbo].[MytableName]
  GROUP BY [TicketID],[OwnedbyTeamT]
  HAVING [OwnedbyTeamT]='B')B
  ON A.[TicketID]=B.[TicketID]
--Fill out the rows on the max dates for the teams 
  WHERE A.Max_DateA>B.Max_DateB
```

You might be able to do with a `PIVOT`. I am leaving a working example.

```
SELECT [TicketID], "A", "B", DATEDIFF(dd,"B","A") AS My_Date_Diff
FROM
(
SELECT [TicketID],[OwnedbyTeamT],MAX([ClosedDate]) AS My_Max
  FROM [YourDB].[dbo].[MytableName]
  GROUP BY [TicketID],[OwnedbyTeamT]
  )Temp
  PIVOT
  (
  MAX(My_Max)
  FOR Temp.[OwnedbyTeamT] in ("A","B")
  )PIV
  WHERE "A">"B"
```